# How to write a poller in spring integration within inbound channel adapter which run synchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

spring integration within inbound channel adapter which run synchronously means second Iteration should run once it completes the first Iteration

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="ProcessingG1" entity-manager="entityManager"
    expect-single-result="false"  
    native-query="SELECT * FROM table1 FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY"
    entity-class="org.entities.Table1"
    >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="ProcessingG1" ref="ProcessingG1" />
```

here the poller is running every 5 seconds and giving the messages to service activator to process, till the service activator processes the messages it should not take next batch

there are 10 poller and same service activators for it I am facing the DB lock issue due to this scenario.

I feel that if iterations were synchronous then it wont create the DB lock as service activator as also trying to update the same table

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing works as expected when you have only one instance of such a polling channel adapter. That `fixed-delay` option is exactly about starting a new task after that time when the previous is done. If you don't an executor on the poller, then your service activator is called from the scheduled thread and it is blocked until your process is done.

If you say that you have "10 poller and same service activators", then it is really expected and natural that you got 10 parallel scheduled tasks against the same source of data.

There are several ways to mitigate your problem:

1. Use DB-specific queries to avoid those records which are locked already in other process. For example, in Oracle there is something like `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` in the `SELECT` syntax. Other DB vendors may provide something similar.
2. Always have only one instance of this poller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#leadership-event-handling
3. You may also play with retry or distributes lock: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-lock-registry